# adding attribute to associate product of configurable product in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'd like to set the value of a custom attribute to an associated product of a configurable product.

1. I've created an attribute and attribute set
2. When I create a configurable product I select the attribute set needed for later selecting the values of each one.

   ```
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
   $stockData = $product->getStockData();
   $stockData['qty'] = $qty;
   $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
   $stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
   $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 1;
   $today = "'".date("Y-m-d")."'";
   $product->setStoreId(0)
       ->setTypeId("configurable")  
       ->setAttributeSetId($attribute_set_id)
       ->setName($es_name)
       ->setDescription($es_description)
       ->setShortDescription($es_short_description)
       ->setSku($sku)
       ->setWeight(1.0)
       ->setStatus(2)  
       ->setVisibility(4) 
       ->setPrice($price)
       ->setTaxClassId($tax_class)  // Impuestos
       ->setStockData($stockData)   // Stock
       ->setCategoryIds($categories) 
       ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))  // Website total
       ->setData('news_from_date', $today)
           ->save();
   ```
3. I have to create as many associated products as attributes selected of the attribute set. For example: custom_attribute with options 40,41,42. So I must create a simple product with my custom_attribute and value and don't know how to do it.
   For example: create a simple product the same as the configurable with my custom_attribute 40 and another with value 42. Knowing that one or more attributes can be associated to the same attribute set and everything must be created dinamically.

Is there something such as $product->setAttribute("custom_attribute",$value)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you're already using it. Magento uses magic methods - to set the value of the attribute custom_attribute to $value, do this:

```
$product->setCustomAttribute($value)
```

To set the value of some_other_thing to $value, do this:

```
$product->setSomeOtherThing($value)
```

Seeing the pattern?

Or, you can use the setData method directly:

```
$product->setData('custom_attribute', $value)
```